# Get image from web to UIImageView don't works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I have a big problem with very simple code.
I need to get a picture from a Facebook URL and put it on a UIImageView.

I don't know but don't works.
I have tried different links also (no Facebook links also don't works).

```
-(IBAction)setUserPhoto:(id)sender{

    NSURL *url = [url initWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/100000769380612/picture?type=large"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    if(image){

        NSLog(@"Image OK");

    } else if (!image) {

            NSLog(@"Error");

    }

    [userPhoto setImage:image];

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something in url..it contain %@ , please replace it with proper string

for eg :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/DoloresPark/picture?type=large
```

you URL should be some thing like the above one

```
-(IBAction)setUserPhoto:(id)sender{

      NSString *user = @"DoloresPark";

      NSString *urlString = [NSString 
                             stringWithFormat:
                             @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",user];

      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

      NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

     if(image){

         NSLog(@"Image OK");

     } else if (!image) {

         NSLog(@"Error");

    }

    [userPhoto setImage:image];

}
```

Comment: No, i have changed it. There are other problems.

Comment: i just edited my answer please try it , its working fine for me

Answer (score 5):

The string has a substitution variable in it, that hasn't been substituted:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large
```

You are missing the alias (thats the error i get if i put this url into safari)

Use

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", replacement]; //where replacement is the string that is supposed to go there
NSUrl *url = [NSUrl URLWithString:urlString];
```

Try the url in the web browser first, to ensure it exists.

Comment: NSURL *url = [url initWithString:urlString]; this line will cause crash , so please use NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]

Comment: ..@Rajesh, yup, I wasn't paying attention that it was an init method... answer updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not making a connection to the URL.Use the following -

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"]];    
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

your class should implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate -

Use the following delegate methods to get the data -

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Using NSURLRequest will perform an asynchronous request, but dataWithContentsOfURL should still get the image.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` and reading the &error for any pointers?